# How do I stop execution of bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, tcpdump

I have script with a loop:

```
until [ $n -eq 0 ]
do
    tcpdump -i eth0 -c 1000000 -s 0 -vvv -w /root/nauvoicedump/`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"`.pcap
    n=$(($n-1))
    echo $n 'times left'
done
```

I want to understand how to stop execution of this script? `<CTRL> + <C>` only stops the following iteration of the loop.

Comment: Have you tried pushing `Ctrl-C` many times or holding it for a longer time?

Comment: How about `Ctrl-Z` and then `kill -9 %`.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGINT` does not terminate the 'following iteration of the loop'.  Rather, when you type ctrl-C, you are sending a `SIGINT` to the currently running instance of tcpdump, and the loop continues after it terminates.  A simple way to avoid this is to trap `SIGINT` in the shell:

```
trap 'kill $!; exit' INT
until [ $n -eq 0 ]
do
    tcpdump -i eth0 -c 1000000 -s 0 -vvv -w /root/nauvoicedump/`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"`.pcap&
    wait
    n=$(($n-1))
    echo $n 'times left'
done
```

Note that you need to run tcpdump in the background (append `&` to the line that starts it) for this to work.  If you have other background jobs running, you may need `wait $!` rather than just `wait`.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the starting value of n at least 1 higher than 0. Example:

```
n=100
until [ "$n" -eq 0 ]
...
```

It's also a good practice to quote your variables properly.

Also it's probably better if you use a for loop:

```
for (( n = 100; n--; )); do
    tcpdump -i eth0 -c 1000000 -s 0 -vvv -w "/root/nauvoicedump/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M').pcap"
    echo "$n times left"
done
```

Comment: of cause I set n before)) it was just a part of the script

Comment: @titusjaka It's a rare case when CTRL-C can't break a loop.